# About the Remainder operator in ansi C

Tags: c

I'm a student of Computer Science and I have a question about the remainder operator in C. I knew that the operator acts as follows:

```
7 % 4 //the result is 3
```

But I read a code in a book that was about programming a deck of cards in which the author used the remainder operator to fill the deck using 2 variables (faces are 13 and suits are 4) as follows:

```
 for (i=0; i<52; i++) {
     face=i%13; // face will have values from 0 to 12
```

I just can't figure out the logic of this computing. Can someone explain me this please?

Comment: In C, you index from `0`. Remainder (more usually modulus) of `1 % 13` is `1`, not `0`. You edited the question since this comment.

Comment: What particularly do you and do you not understand from the example? My bet is that your actual problem has nothing to do with `%` at all.

Comment: I thuoght the remainder was intended  to be used with left operand bigger than the right operand.

Comment: @Grugnas If you have `a % b` where `a < b`, then `a` divided by `b` is 0 with rest `a`, so `a % b == a`

Comment: (@melpomene's comment assumes `0 <= a` as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic is simple. Its a simple mathematics. If you divide a integer number `p` with `q` (`q != 0`) then the remainder can't be greater than `q-1`.

Comment: I'm sorry I intended to use the %  when  P is bigger than Q, this is the reason why I had doubts about that. While   i < 13  the compiler gave me numbers from 0 to 12 and i simply didn't understand the reason when I read the code in the book.

Comment: In order to clarify the issue the function is repetitive. Given 2 numbers **p** and **q** with **p>=q** the operation `p%q` will give a result **R[0-q]** for any **q=[0-q]*n**

Comment: @Frankie_C - Shouldn't that be 0 -> (q-1)? On a side note, in C integer division round towards zero instead of towards negative infinity (which is how it's done in mathematics and other languages). So if the remainder is not zero, it has the same sign as the dividend. In the case of mathematics, a non-zero remainder has the same sign as the divisor.

Comment: @rcgldr: Yes, you're right. I should have write **R[0-(q-1)]**. In plain word if we have **p=10** and **q=2**, **p%q** for p=3 => R=1, p=4 => R=0, p=9 => R=1 and p=10 => R=0.